# Type 'T' does not conform to protocol 'EntityType'

Tags: swift

I think the type relationships are rather plain here and yet I'm missing the cause for the error.  The error is: "Type 'T' does not conform to protocol 'EntityType'" (at `ThingManager`):

```
//
protocol EntityType {
  typealias Identifier
  var identifier : Identifier { get }
}

class EntityWithStringIdentifier : EntityType {
  var identifier : String
  init (i:String) { self.identifier = i }
}

class Thing : EntityWithStringIdentifier {}

//
protocol EntityManager {
  typealias Entity : EntityType
  func has (entity:Entity) -> Bool
}

class BaseEntityManager<Entity:EntityType> : EntityManager {
  func has (entity:Entity) -> Bool { return true }
}

// Type 'T' does not conform to protocol 'EntityType'
class ThingManager<T:Thing> : BaseEntityManager<T> {
}
```

`T` is a subtype of `Thing`; `Thing` is a subtype of `EntityWithStringIdentifier` which implements `EntityType`.  ***So, why the error***?

Apparently the error is avoidable by using:

```
class ThingManager<T:Thing where T:EntityType> : BaseEntityManager<T> {
}
```

and then one can instantiate a `ThingManager` with `Thing` (implying `Thing` implemented `EntityType` in the first place...)

```
var tm = ThingManager<Thing>()
```

From a type perspective, is there a better way to implement this kind of DAO pattern?

Comment: i don´t understand why do you do this way? This smell much complex code for a simples solution. Do you can explain better what you want do?

Comment: @ViTUu I think what GoZoner wants to do is achieve some polymorphism. This actually looks like a pretty straightforward implementation to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the announcement of Swift 2.0, it seems pointless to answer this question in terms of earlier versions of Swift, which will very soon be obsolete. I can confirm that this problem—which I believe to be a bug—still exists as of this writing in Swift 2.0. However, I can suggest a slightly different way to organize the code that mitigates the problem while still having a clean implementation: Skip the `ThingManager` class and use a protocol extension instead.

So, leaving all your code the same up to `BaseEntityManager`, you'd have:

```
// NOTE "where Entity: Thing". This is the key.
extension EntityManager where Entity: Thing {
  func useAThing(thing: Thing) {

  }
}

let tm = BaseEntityManager<Thing>()
tm.useAThing(Thing(i: "thing"))
```

I suspect this will end up being the "Swift way" of doing things. Swift's generics are just plain strange to me. They constantly violate the Principle of Least Surprise, IMHO. But ultimately they are quite powerful if you learn their quirks. The only drawback of this approach is with access modifiers and encapsulation. The `useAThing` method has no access to the private state of `EntityManagerBase`, which may or may not be a problem depending on your circumstances.

Lastly, if you take this approach, I recommend some renaming. `BaseEntityManager` feels like the wrong name if you never subclass it. Instead, I would call it `EntityManager` and rename the protocol to `EntityManagerType` to follow Apple's conventions.